# angular ui-router stateParams persisting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

i am using ui-router for my SPA but I am having issues with the states. My state is setup as below

```
$stateProvider.state('product', {
    url: '/product/:category/:product',
    templateUrl: 'src/app/product/product.tpl.html',
    controller: 'ProductCtrl'
});
```

But the issue I am having is that when I go to /product/cat-one my controller handles the fact there is no product set, then when i go to /product/cat-one/product-one my controller again handles the fact there is a product present, which all works well.

The problem im facing is that if i go to /product/cat-two from /product/cat-one/product-one the :product persists and the url ends up being /product/cat-two/product-one.

Can anybody point me in the right direction on this one please?

This is my controller for reference:

```
.controller( 'ProductCtrl', function ( $scope, $stateParams, ProductService ) {
  $scope.categoryId  = $stateParams.category;
  $scope.productId   = $stateParams.product;
  $scope.isProduct   = false;

  if ($scope.productId) {
      $scope.isProduct = true;
      $scope.item = ProductService.getProduct($scope.categoryId);
  } else {
      $scope.item = ProductService.getCategory($scope.categoryId);
  }
})
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at this part `ProductService.getProduct($scope.categoryId)`

Comment: those functions are currently just returning mock data. but looking at it it would be that the productId is set in that controller therefore its is holding it. I guess the question im asking is how would i set up my states so that these 2 pages are different without having to create 2 seperate modules

Comment: I ment that you don't use `$scope.productId`, anyway, what do you use to change states? `ui-sref` or `$state.go()` ?

Comment: i use ui-sref. the reason $scope.productId isnt used in that example is because whatever i pass into those functions it just returns the same thing. so even if i did pass it in it wouldnt make a difference to the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really looks like you should be handling this route setup hierarchically:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('category', { url: '/product/:category', templateUrl: 'src/app/product/product.tpl.html', controller: 'ProductCtrl' })
    .state('category.product', { url: '/:product', templateUrl: 'src/app/product/product.tpl.html', controller: 'ProductCtrl' });
```

Now I am not sure on your requirements, but it also might be a good idea to have another parent state ('/product') that abstracts the reused functionality of both categories and products.

---

Ok, so it looks like the requirements are for showing a single product and single category. I would suggest having a good read of the ui-router documentation when you get a chance. To get the functionality you desire, you should be using a separate template and controller for categories and products.

If you want to completely replace the category page with the product page, then the states should not be hierarchical, however if they borrow reused functionality you could have a parent state to both types that can implement this reusability (but I would more likely use a service here).

So the resulting route definition would be as follows:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('category', { url: '/product/:category', templateUrl: 'src/app/product/category.tpl.html', controller: 'CategoryCtrl' })
    .state('product', { url: '/product/:category/:product', templateUrl: 'src/app/product/product.tpl.html', controller: 'ProductCtrl' });
```

Note that you now need a template and controller for each type.

Comment: this dosnt seem to fix the issue unfortunately. /product does not have a state as it /product/:category should be used to show a category and /product/:category/:product should be used to show a single product from the category. When i tried the above the category worked but when adding a product to the end of the url it didnt even react

Comment: Yeah thats where I was thinking I may have to head. I couldnt find any examples of what I am trying to achieve so i will go with your suggestion as i know that will work. thanks for the help